# Why is this relay circuit with an ESP32 not working?

Tags: microcontroller, arduino, relay, esp32

I have set up a circuit as described in the picture. The circuit works so far, the ESP switches all relays and switches on the circuits.

The problem is that as soon as I connect the motor, which is connected to relay 4 with the 9V power source and switch relay 4, the motor starts up for about 2 seconds and then the ESP restarts and the relay closes again.

[image: circuit image]
(I have redrawn the relays below for better understanding)

The motor should not actually be able to take any electricity from the ESP since it has its own circuit with the motor of relay 2. If I take a new 9V power source and connect the motor to it so that the motor on relay 4 has its own circuit, everything works again.

Where did I go wrong?

Comment: This site has a easy to use schematic editor.  It would be really helpful to have a legible schematic vs. what you have posted.

Comment: I can not clearly understand your schematic. Please use this site's schematic editor as @jwh20 said.

Comment: If using an off the shelf relay board can you provide part number and a picture of your setup?

Comment: If you have difficulty to do with schematic editor, re-draw on your sheet NEATLY. This unfortunately looks illegible.

Comment: I'm sorry, I didnt know about the schematics function in the editor's toolbar

Answer (score 1):

If everything is OK until you close or open relay contact applied to the motor, it means it is an electromagnetic compatibility problem.

Use a snubber circuit which can be simply a freewheeling diode for DC motors at the motor terminals to avoid electromagnetic interference. Add diodes on both motors.

[image]

Comment: Wait! Motor 4 (seems to be) connected to 240V (AC maybe) his schematic is not clear to me.
Ac on a simple diode will cause a short.

Comment: No the 230V is for the lamp I think.

Comment: Thanks for your answers, 230V is for the lamp.